# Java Regex validate String

Tags: java, regex

There are lot of similar questions on the Regex, however I am still confused on the following case:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PatternTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String PATTERN = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,20})";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(PATTERN);

    boolean isTrue = pattern.matcher("nks#n1Kos2~([{&").matches();

    System.out.println(isTrue);
  }

}
```

The characters of `~([{&` is not in the PATTERN, however the `matches` shows up `true`. What is the reason for that?

Here is a link on `Java Regular Expression Tester` https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: to help with confusion whet do `.{8,20}` match, yes ? not wise to restrict to set of characters for passwords. hackers guess that, combinations is doable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is:

```
String PATTERN = "(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{8,20}";
```

Which means match **any character** of 8 to 20 in length that fulfills all the conditions given in lookahead.

What you actually need is this:

```
String PATTERN = "(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%])[a-zA-Z\\d@#$%]{8,20}";
```

`[a-zA-Z\\d@#$%]{8,20}` will match only allowed characters inside `[...]` 8 to 20 in length.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z\\d@#$%]` works, however it's kind of clumsy for it needs to list all of the characters once more.

Answer (score 2):

The `(?=X)` patterns are "zero-width positive lookahead" assertions. So they're asserting that the regexes are found in the search string *without consuming any of it*. All of these assertions are passing successfully.

The `.{8,20}` pattern is saying "match any character as long as there are between 8 and 20 of them (inclusive)". So it is matching the entire string.